# Protect Solr server that is queried by Ajax

Tags: ajax, security, search, proxy, solr

On my development system I have a Solr server running that is queried by a local web application using Ajax-Solr.

I guess on a production system I have to protect the Solr server somehow that only query requests can be made that are predefined.

What is the best way for such a protection? Does (swiss army knife) Solr also have something like that built in? Or do I have to use a proxy server? If yes, what would be an easy one to setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option you can do is set up a reverse proxy on an apache server, that translates a url into the solr request.  you can do this by simply only making a reverse proxy entry for the "select" or "spell" function of solr, so:
mydomain.com/solr_search could point to localhost:8080/solrname/select|spell

then you lock down the solr port so it can only be used by local host requests.

Answer (score 1):

This topic came up on the ajax-solr mailing list recently: http://groups.google.com/group/ajax-solr/browse_thread/thread/a4bb587e6f3723df

Other ways of locking down Solr includes using invariants: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration

You can also disable updates and deletes, but I can't seem to find the documentation.